# AWS+Django+Nginx Unable to server static files

Tags: django, amazon-web-services, nginx

I am having a hard time getting my static files whenever i run the server its shows ""GET /static/css/agency.css HTTP/1.1" 404 179"
I am pretty new to django and trying a basic portfolio app here is my configuration

1.

```
/home/ubuntu/portfolder
                   inside (port folder)
                    portproject
                             inside (django project folder)
                             __init__.py  
                             __pycache__  
                             asgi.py  
                             settings.py  
                             urls.py  
                             wsgi.py
                    django.ppk  
                    app.sock  
                    port_pics
                    logfile  
                    manage.py  
                    media  
                    protappli 
                            inside (django app folder)
                            __init__.py  
                            __pycache__  
                            admin.py  
                            apps.py  
                            forms.py  
                            migrations  
                            models.py  
                            templates  
                            templatetags  
                            tests.py  
                            views.py
 
                    static
                            admin  
                            css  
                            custom  
                            img  
                            js  
                            mail  
                            scss  
                            vendor
```

The settings.py file

```
STATIC_URL = '/static/'
STATIC_ROOT = '/home/ubuntu/portfolder/static/'

'''STATICFILES_DIRS = [
    os.path.join(BASE_DIR, '/static/'),
]'''
```

nginx config file

```
server {
        #listen [::]:80;
        listen [::]:1234;
        server_name 13.59.57.0 ec2-13-59-57-0.us-east-2.compute.amazonaws.com;

        location / {
                include proxy_params;
                proxy_pass http://unix:/home/ubuntu/portfolder/app.sock;
        }
        location /static/ {
                autoindex on;
                root /home/ubuntu/portfolder;
                proxy_pass http://13.59.57.0:8000/home/ubuntu/portfolder/static/;
                #expires 7d;
        }
        location  /media/ {
                autoindex off;
                root /home/ubuntu/portfolder;
                expires 7d;
        }
        location ~* .(jpg|svg|jpeg|gif|png|ico|css|zip|rar|pdf)$ {
                alias /home/ubuntu/portfolder/;
                error_page 404 = 404;
        }
}
```

I have tried doing everything i had referred to 10-12 similar queries from stack overflow but none of them showed any promising results.

thanks in advance